# Multiple Projects in Xcode Workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-workspace

I created a workspace and added two projects in Xcode workspace. One new and one existing. I want to access a storyboard of an existing project within a tap of a button in new project. Can I do that?

Existing project is linked with a lot of libraries and one of them is Tapku library. It works fine, but I want to have a new project and some buttons there, that when I tap a button I access an existing projects storyboard and then work with that so called application.

thank you.

This is what I tried to do:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and I have error:

```
Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPad' in bundle NSBundle "somePath/Application1.app (loaded)
```

This storyboard is in Application2 Project.

Comment: Obviously you should add the correct bundle name for 'Main_iPad'

Comment: 'Main_iPad' is a storyboard in Application2.xcodeproject, but I want to present that storyboard on a click of a button in Application1.xcodeproject.
Can you help me?

Comment: it should be something like this: UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithPath:"somePath/Application2.app"]];

Comment: @jackPolski, I have same issue, need to access projectA's XIB into projectB under same workspace